# Ejabberd Connection in Golang with tls confg

Tags: go, ejabberd

I have set up ejabberd  setup on server1 and my golang code is running on server2 and certificates are on server1. Now I have to make connection with ejabberd in golang with tls config.

My question is that where I have to place certificate on server1 or server2?

Error : Failed to read root CA certificate file :path/to/root_ca.crt: no such file or directory

If I not set rootCas in config Error I faced is : tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

My code is given below

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/mattn/go-xmpp/xmpp"
)

func main() {
    // Load the root CA certificate from a file
    caCertFile := "path/to/root_ca.crt"
    caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile(caCertFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to read root CA certificate file: %v", err)
    }

    // Create a new certificate pool and add the root CA certificate
    rootCAs := x509.NewCertPool()
    if ok := rootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert); !ok {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to add root CA certificate to the pool")
    }

    options := xmpp.Options{
        Host:      "your_ejabberd_host",
        User:      "your_username",
        Password:  "your_password",
        Debug:     true,
        NoTLS:     false,
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{RootCAs: rootCAs},
    }

    conn, err := options.NewClient()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to create XMPP client:", err)
    }

    // Send a sample message
    err = conn.Send(xmpp.Chat{
        Remote: "recipient_jid@example.com",
        Type:   "chat",
        Text:   "Hello, this is a test message!",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to send message:", err)
    }
    conn.Close()
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> path/to/root_ca.crt: no such file or directory

The error message is obvious. You should copy this file from the ejabberd server to the client.

> tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

See [the doc of the tls option of ejabberd](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/listen-options/#tls), the `tls` method is nowadays deprecated and not recommended. It's most likely that the ejabberd server is configured to use the `STARTTLS` encryption method. In this case, `NoTLS` in `xmpp.Options` should be set to `true`.

And you should specify `ServerName` or `InsecureSkipVerify` in the `tls.Config`. Otherwise, you will see this error message:

```
starttls handshake: tls: either ServerName or InsecureSkipVerify must be specified in the tls.Config
```

If your purpose is to make your demo work, you can simply set
`NoTLS: true` and `InsecureSkipVerify: true`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"

    "github.com/mattn/go-xmpp"
)

func main() {
    options := xmpp.Options{
        Host:     "your_ejabberd_host",
        User:     "your_username",
        Password: "your_password",
        Debug:    true,
        NoTLS:    true,
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    }

    conn, err := options.NewClient()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = conn.Send(xmpp.Chat{
        Remote: "recipient_jid@example.com",
        Type:   "chat",
        Text:   "Hello, this is a test message!",
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    conn.Close()
}
```